# C++ - no operator "<<" matches these operands directory_iterator()

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I've copied the example code on the [directory_iterator page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator), so this is what I have:

```
#include "pch.h" //for visual studios benefit
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    fs::create_directories("sandbox/a/b");
    std::ofstream("sandbox/file1.txt");
    std::ofstream("sandbox/file2.txt");
    for (auto& p : fs::directory_iterator("sandbox"))
        std::cout << p << '\n'; //this line on the first '<<' is where the error occurs
    fs::remove_all("sandbox");
    return 0; //included by me
}
```

And the error message is:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0349   no operator "<<" matches these operands
```

As I'm new to C++ I might have gotten things wrong, but my understanding of the error is basically that `p` in my case is something which can't be printed out to the console using `cout`.

The example works if I run it directly on the page so there isn't something wrong with it, which I wouldn't expect either. So question is, why am I seeing this error?

I use the latest version of Visual Studio, along with C++ 2017.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`directory_entry` doesn't have streaming support directly; it gets it via `path`'s `operator<<` plus an implicit conversion to `const std::filesystem::path &`.

As a result of [LWG issues 2989](https://wg21.link/LWG2989) and [3065](https://wg21.link/LWG3065), `path`'s operators have been made into hidden friends, and can no longer be used to stream things convertible to a `path`, such as a `directory_entry`.

The fix is to ask for `.path()` directly rather than depend on the implicit conversion. I've fixed the cppreference example.

---

After checking with LWG, this change appears to be unintended. I've filed [LWG 3171](https://wg21.link/LWG3171).

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure now whether [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53429663/2411320) is correct after reading yours T.C, nice answer!

Comment: I don't know if I'm in a position to determine if using `path()` or the `experimental` namspace is more correct than the other. So I won't accept an answer until I get more enlighted within the subjet. They both work however, rendering a slightly different output. Using `path()` will render "" around each find, while `experimental` namespace will not. The data is still the same though.

Comment: `experimental` gets you the older filesystem TS implementation, which [will be removed in the next ABI-breaking release of MSVC](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/05/07/announcing-msvc-conforms-to-the-c-standard/).

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
```

to this:

```
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
```

because VS 17 uses an experimental version of the `filesystem`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `std::experimental` namespace:

```
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
```

Comment: Hey Peter, I believe you are right, but I don't see what that answer adds further than my answer and Matthieu's... :/

Comment: Yes you're right. I just tried the sample in vs2017 and posted the answer here. Sorry, I didn't see your answers.

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2017 (15.8 and 15.9 if I'm not mistaken), `filesystem` only exposes an experimental version, so use:

```
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
```